# Re-mounting an un-mounted USB stick

Tags: usb, mount, live-usb, unmount, eject

Is there a way to mount back a USB stick that is once ejected, without physically detaching it and then plugging it in?

It was a live-usb of Linux Mint 14 in it, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mount a device by typing i.e. `sudo mount /dev/sdxX /mnt` (change "xX" to your device)

Identify your USB-Stick by `sudo fdisk -l` to know the devicename and partition number which looks like `sdbxX` i.e. `sdb1`

Comment: You can do this only if the device is unmounted. It is not possible to remount an ejected USB device without restarting the USB port the device is connected to (which is a huge overkill imo). 

The question should make up its mind whether it wants to mount ejected devices or unmounted devices.

Comment: Have you tried `mount -o remount -rw <mountpoint>`?

Comment: When you eject a USB device the device node is destroyed. There is nothing to mount.

Comment: Can I get it back in connection with the PC once I eject it? Without removing and plugging it back in?

Comment: @utkuerd, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74066/14907, btw -1 for weak answer that only works when device is not actually ejected but only umounted.